# Why is this join not working in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to output everything for table one where there is a mention like something from table two

table one is the aoldataleak from 2006 and table two is a created table of all contestants in a horse race at that time period

```sql
select query,
       PFERDENAME
from   AOLDATA.querydata,
       Pferde
where  query like ( '%' ||PFERDENAME||'%')
ORDER BY PFERDENAME;
```

Pferdename is a column in table 2 and query is a column in table one

both are chars and the output I get is just a blank table, but I know for a fact there are querys in the first table that are like Pferdenamen in the second one.

I tried this same statement with a dummy table with only a few entries and there it worked just fine

Comment: Without exact tables' description and sample data, it is difficult to guess what might be wrong. Consider posting it.

Comment: so table one has an ID(id of the google search) and AnonID(id of the specific searcher) query(the thing that was searched)  querytime(at what time that was searched) itemrank(the rank of the link that was clicked after the search) clickurl(specific link that was cliked) and table two was created like this CREATE TABLE Pferde
( Pferdename CHAR (25) PRIMARY KEY,
Startnummer int,
Platzierung int,
Gewinnchance char (5),
Gewinn char (10),
Jockey char (20),
Zeit char (8));

Answer (score 2):

So here's error cause:

```
Pferdename CHAR (25) PRIMARY KEY
```

`CHAR` datatype right-pads values with spaces up to the max column length. So, if horse name is "Max", Oracle stores it as "Max" followed by 22 spaces (which alltogether make 3 + 22 = 25 characters).

You shouldn't

- use `CHAR` in such a case; use `VARCHAR2` instead
- name is not the best choice for a primary key; it means that there can't be two horses whose names are "Max"

If it must be `CHAR`, then you'd better **trim** it, e.g.

```
select query, PFERDENAME 
from AOLDATA.querydata, Pferde 
where query like ( '%' || trim(PFERDENAME) ||'%') 
ORDER BY PFERDENAME;
```

---

Example:

```
SQL> with
  2  querydata (query) as
  3    (select 'This is Max, my favorite horse' from dual),
  4  pferde (pferdename) as
  5    (select 'Max        ' from dual)
  6  select query, pferdename
  7  from querydata, pferde
  8  where query like ( '%' || trim(pferdename) ||'%')
  9  order by pferdename;

QUERY                          PFERDENAME
------------------------------ -----------
This is Max, my favorite horse Max

SQL>
```

Comment: hmm okay, this gives me expression missing as an error, and horse can be the primary key in this spec. case because we know the names are unique

Comment: I don't know what you did to get the error, because query *works*; see edited answer which now contains an example.